# Custom legend in grafana panel using template expressions not working

Tags: grafana, go-templates, grafana-loki

I have a grafana v10.2.2 dashboard time series panel and I'm struggling to customize the legend on it.

[According to the docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/), I could use templates like the following to customize the values shown, but instead I'm getting the booth results.

Expression used:

```
{{ if eq "1" "2" }} true {{ else }} false {{ end }}
```

Results:
[image: Grafana dashboard label]

My practical use case is to show a label value `app` if it is defined or the fixed value "Unknown" when it's absent.

I tried it with `if` and  `unless` blocks, but none of the functions seemed to work, the function blocks are being ignored.

Thanks for any thoughts shared on it.

Comment: OK, please show your LogQL query to see how did you use that template

Comment: Diego, are you trying to use provided expression in the field *Legend* of the query? If so - it is not supposed to work. Mentioned syntax is only supposed to work in the query itself. Legend is not supporting any kind of logic, AFAIK. But you can "bake in" your logic into the query itself, as shown in the Jan's answer.

Comment: Yes, @markalex I was trying to use the _Legend_ field. I ended up mixing the information I was getting from chatgpt + docs :sweat_smile: Thanks for checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to implement real case: `My practical use case is to show a label value app if it is defined or the fixed value "Unknown" when it's absent.`

Let's transform it to: `app` label should have original app label value or if `app` label doesn't exist then `app` label should have value `Unknown`.

See linked doc:

> The text template format used in | line_format and | label_format support the usage of functions.

So this is not Grafana feature (not Grafana's time series `Legend` field, which looks like you have used), but Loki query feature and it must be applied in the LogQL query.

For example:

```
{
  selector=~".+"
}
| json
| label_format app="{{ if .app }}{{ .app }}{{ else }}Unknown{{ end }}"
```

Example query may need some tweak (if there is any syntax issue, ...)

Of course real query depends on format of your real logs. Just see example how mentioned template can be used in `label_format`. Just use then that `app` label in Grafana's time series `Legend` field (as `{{app}}`).

Comment: You're completely right. I mixed up the things here. Using that function directly in the query it works like a charm, I just had to take off the `| json`  that seems not to be needed in my case. As @markalex said, the _Legend_ field of the query doesn't support functions and is being ignored. Thanks.